# Parse date with Python library "ParseDateTime"

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, datetime, time

Hello everyone, 
I'm using the library "ParseDateTime" to convert a date as a string into type date.

E.g:
Oct 4 = ' 2015-10-04 00:00:00 '

**I Try this:**

```
    import parsedatetime as pdt

    c = pdt.Constants()
    p = pdt.Calendar(c)
    f = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

    data_format = p.parseDT(date_time)
    print data_format[0].strftime(f)
```

This code works, but strangely i see 2016 instead of 2015.

So I see this:
' **2016**-10-04 00:00:00 '

Thanks

Comment: Are you passing an empty string, today, tomorrow, next year  to `parseDT` or what exactly?

Comment: date_time is my date string for example date_time = "Oct 4".
In this case should be implicit the current year (2015).But the year 2016 is put .

These dates,are presents in the questions and answers of a Q&A site(Quora ).

E.g:
https://www.quora.com/Python-programming-language-1/What-are-some-cool-Python-tricks

You can see the date at the top (Last Asked) for the question, and for each single answer ( Written or Updated ) . I would like to acquire these.

The problem comes when it is not specified year. (In this page, for example , in the top left there is Last asked: 4 Oct)

Comment: don't put additional info in the comments, [edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse `"Oct 4"`, you could use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime("Oct 4", "%b %d")
datetime.datetime(1900, 10, 4, 0, 0)
>>> d = datetime.strptime("Oct 4", "%b %d")
>>> datetime(datetime.now().year, d.month, d.day)
datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 4, 0, 0)
```

If you want dates from the past; pass "Jan 1" for the corresponding year as the source time (default is the current time "Oct 25"):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import parsedatetime as pdt # $ pip install parsedatetime
>>> cal = pdt.Calendar()
>>> cal.parseDT("Oct 4") # today is Oct 25
(datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 4, 14, 19, 9), 1)
>>> cal.parseDT("Oct 4", datetime(2015, 1, 1))
(datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 4, 0, 0), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks But I Solved with this:

c.YearParseStyle = 0